# Agregar elementos de una columna de un archivo excel a un arreglo en python

Tags: excel, pandas

Tengo un archivo en excel con dos columnas, y quisiera agregar la segunda columna de excel a un arreglo: dicha columna tiene alrededor de 1800 filas, sin embargo no encuentro cómo hacerlo.

El código sí me lee el archivo pero no agrega los elementos al arreglo. La segunda columna se llama *onda*:

```
import pandas as pd

import openpyxl

archivo = pd.read_excel('muestra.xlsx')

numero_onda = [archivo [['onda']]]
```

Comment: `numero_onda = archivo.onda.values`

Comment: `numero_onda = archivo['onda'].to_list()`